# What is the importance of `&` when overloading the `[]` operator for a container class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, container-classes

Let's say I have this simple container class

```cpp
class Array{
private:
    int m_l{};
    int *m_d{};


public:
    Array() = default;

    Array(int len)
        : m_l{len}
    {
        assert(len >= 0);
        if (len > 0)
        {
            m_d = new int[len]{};
        }
    }
    ~Array(){
        delete[] m_d;
    }

// -------------------------------------------
    int& operator[](int i){
        assert(i >= 0 && i <= m_l && "Index in operator [] out of range");
        return m_d[i];
    }
//--------------------------------------------
};
```

Specifically

```cpp
int& operator[](int i)
{
    assert(i >= 0 && i <= m_l && "Index in operator [] out of range");
    return m_d[i];
}
```

I have overloaded the `[]` operator to get the subscript, I am just learning about operator overloading and container classes.

```cpp
Array arr{5};
arr[0] = 32;
arr[1] = 34;
std::cout << arr[0];
```

> 32

The code compiles and executes as expected, but if I remove the `&` from the function, making it

```cpp
int operator[](int i)
{
    assert(i >= 0 && i <= m_l && "Index in operator [] out of range");
    return m_d[i];
}
```

The compiler throws an error

> lvalue required as left of operand assignment

Why does this error occur, what is the significance of `&` in the function?

Comment: Your constructor does not assign the pointer if the length is 0.  The destructor is not checking the length before calling `delete[]`, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: the program will terminate if the length is 0 due to `assert()`

Comment: The `assert(len >= 0);` won't terminate with a len of 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the reference in the subscript operator overload, you are returning a temporary rvalue from the function. An rvalue cannot occur on the left side of an assignment operation.

Specifically, when you write `arr[0]`, without the reference in your overload that would just return an integer (as whatever the value of arr[0] is).

```
Array arr{5};
arr[0]; //Without the reference, this returns 5.
5 = 32; //Written out, this is what the expression turns to.
```

The 5 is an rvalue that cannot be assigned to - what would `5 = 32` mean? With the reference overload, you are returning a reference (the memory location) to the first element of the array which is an lvalue. Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) might help you understand it better.

Comment: can you explain a little more? as you would to a novice

Comment: But if I do `std::cout << arr[0]`, I get the value of `arr[0]` not the memory location ? What is the difference?

Comment: You get the value, yes, but what is important here is that with `int` that value is a temporary object (a copy) that ceases to exist as soon as it exits it scope. This object has a memory location that is **completely unrelated** to `m_d[i]` that you return from your underlying int array. If you return a reference, you are actually returning the object that you initially put into your array.

Comment: Yes I got that part, I am confused as to why I get `5` if I do `std::cout << arr[0]` and not something like `0x61fe1c` (an address). What I mean is if I have a variable `a` , if I do `std::cout << &a` I get the hex number, but if I have a function that returns a reference to a like `int& s() {return a;}` `std::cout << s()` gives `5` but not the hex

Comment: Because underneath you are using the [array subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at) which returns a reference (as a value). When I said `memory location` in my post, I meant that the object that you are returning is at the same memory location as in the array, not that the actual value will be the memory address.

Comment: I think that is the part i don't understand, returning a reference - as a value

Comment: The value is the reference. `int&` version returns an `int` that refers to the value at `m_d[i]`, i.e. `&(m_d[i]) == &(arr[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` in `int&` means that your `operator[]` returns a *reference* (ie, an alias, usually implemented as a memory address) to an `int` variable.  Once bound to a variable, any value that is assigned to a reference gets assigned to the variable it refers to.

Without the `&`, your `operator[]` would return a *copy* (ie, the value) of the `int` instead.

When a function returns a value rather than a reference, the compiler creates a temporary variable to hold that value. That temporary exists only until the end of the statement that creates it.  That temporary variable is known as an [rvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), ie a value that is used on the right-hand side of an assignment.  To preserve the value longer, the caller must assign it to another variable.

Things like named variables, references to variables, etc are [lvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)s, ie they can used on the left-hand side of an assignment.  An rvalue cannot be used on the left-hand side, only on the right-hand side.